# setting variables efficiently with tkinter callbacks

Tags: python, tkinter

I need to set some variables using tkinter callbacks on a tkinter Button. So I could say (inside of a class definition)

```
Button1 = Button(parentframe, text="set", command = self.setvar)

def setvar(self):
    self.myvar = 7
```

Is there some way to do that with an inline (lambda) function, rather than cluttering things up with silly little callbacks?

```
command = lambda *args: something?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
command = lambda: setattr(self, 'myvar', 7)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this using Tkinter's [integer variable class](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) and a lambda function as you suspected. A variable of type `IntVar` has `.get()` and `.set()` methods that will allow you to, unsurprisingly, get and set its value. Take the following for example:

```
from Tkinter import *


class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        # initialise Integer Variables
        self.example1 = IntVar()
        self.example1.set(2)

        self.text1 = Entry(root, textvariable=self.example1, state=DISABLED)
        self.text1.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.button1 = Button(root, text="Double", command=lambda: self.double_value(self.example1))
        self.button1.grid(row=1, column=0)

    def double_value(self, var):
        var.set(var.get() * 2)


root = Tk()
app = App(root)

root.mainloop()
```

This gives you a bit of flexibility, and could be expanded to apply the same feature to multiple buttons relating to different `Entry` boxes and `IntVar` variables.